# Will `dd` stop if input is larger than output? (output file is a partition)

Tags: partitioning, dd

I want to move one partition to another location on a hard drive, i.e. contents of `sda1` to `sda2`, and then I want to boot from `sda2`.

First of all, I don't know if that's gonna mess up some partition table or something making it not possible to boot, but I'm gonna try. It's a HFS+ partition, and I haven't had any experience with how they behave.

Ignoring that, if I try to `dd` the contents from one to another (I'm actually placing the contents in a file on a separate larger partition), what will happen if `sda2` runs out of space? Will it keep running into the next partition physically located on the drive, or will it simply stop and give an error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what will happen if `sda2` runs out of space?

If you use `of=/dev/sda2` and `sda2` runs out of space then `dd` will exit with `No space left on device`. One of the points of using special files like `/dev/sda2` is making sure you don't read nor write beyond its boundaries within `/dev/sda`.

The resulting filesystem on `sda2` will be corrupt, unless it's small enough to fit in. It's *uncommon* but possible to have a filesystem smaller than a partition holding it. Only in this case `dd`-ing to a smaller (yet large enough) partition will copy the entire filesystem.

But if you used `of=/dev/sda` and `seek=…` to start writing exactly where `sda2` starts, and if your `if` is larger than `sda2`, then `dd` would happily write beyond the end of `sda2`, because it opened the entire `sda` and has access to the whole of it. We use `sdaN` abstraction to avoid such mishaps.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Also, lets say sda2 is a little bit larger though, maybe by just 1 or 2 MB, and it was already containing a file system before of=sda2. If sda1 was a file system, and I want to dd if=sda1 of=sda2, would it matter if I zeroed sda2, or can I just leave whatever bits are already set there?

Comment: @simernes In this case you can leave those bits at the end. Every filesystem should know how large it is (filesystems store this information in their headers, in your case I think this is relevant: [totalBlocks in HFS+](http://dubeyko.com/development/FileSystems/HFSPLUS/hexdumps/hfsplus_volume_header.html#totalBlocks)), extra space beyond its end (zeroed or not) makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

If you are dd'ing directly into `of=/dev/sda2`:

Partition device nodes are bounded by the kernel according to the partition table, so all writes beyond the end will return -ENOSPC ("No space left on device"). Upon receiving any sort of write error, dd will stop.